# Node.js error on calling Api

Tags: node.js

I get this error ""Error: Unable to determine the domain name". This is my node.js code

```
var iplocation = "https://localhost:7000";
    var rule_url = "/renewtoken" 
var HTTP = require("http");
customerid = 'snWkzJMDSrjV';
                    //HTTP.call("POST", "https://httpbin.org/post",
                    //HTTP.call("GET", iplocation + "/api/v1/aws/iamusersmfaenabled/" + customerid,
                    HTTP.get("POST", iplocation + rule_url ,
                      {
                        data: {customerId: customerid}
                      },
                      function (error, result) {
                        if (!error) 
                        {
                            console.log("--------------");
                        }else
                        {


                        }
                    });
```

When I run this code 
this error occur

"Error: Unable to determine the domain name

Comment: `HTTP.get("POST",` ??? `localhost:?000` ???

Comment: First I wrote http.call but that give error that "http.call is not a function". Localhost:?000 mean there is a number in place of ? but I not want to show :-)

Comment: "?" in iplocation.

Comment: if you want to POST, use `HTTP.post(url)`. Then you'll only need to fix the strange port in your iplocation and you're good to go

Comment: Friend there is a number in place of ? but I not want to show because of company policy

Comment: @baao friend "TypeError: HTTP.post is not a function
" this error I occured after changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all friends for helping me.
When I call this APi with request keyword also add request package and change format then It's work.

```
var request = require('request')
var iplocation = "https://localhost:7000";
var url = "/api/v1/scan"
urlparams = "?customerId=[ijklmnop,qrstuvzx]&region=[us-east-1,us-west-1]&emailAddress=[def@gmail.com,def@gmail.com]"
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

request({
    uri: iplocation + url + urlparams,
    method: "POST"
    // followRedirect: true,
    // maxRedirects: 10
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log("result1 " + body);
        console.log("result2 " + response)
    }
});
```